# Passing an object in URI jquery and accessing it in php

Tags: php, jquery, object, uri, param

I have a quick question here. I would like to pass an object through the uri.

So here is a set of data I am using already something like this:

```
a = 'a';
b = 'b';

obj = {
 d : 'd',
 c : 'c'
}

//so now URLencode
var data = '?a=' + URLEncode(a);
var data += '&b=' + URLEncode(b);
var data += '&obj=' + $.param(obj);

loadPage(url, data);
```

So when I load this in my PHP I would like to be able to access the `obj` as an array and something like this:

```
<?php
...
$_obj =  $this->_request->getParam('obj');

 echo $_obj[d];
 echo $_obj[c];
```

output of course would be this:

```
d
c
```

So, in conclusion how would you go about and do this so that my php works as shown above?
I really appreciate your help and thank you in advance!

Comment: Charlietfl, sorry about that! I updated the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    data += "&obj[" + encodeURIComponent(key) + "]=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
});
```

Comment: Hi explosion Pills, I know I didn't mention this in my question, but what if there is an object within an object? Say for example: `obj={a:a, b:b, b:{c:c, d:d}}` Thanks!

Comment: In that case it would be much easier to just convert the object to a json string (`JSON.stringify`) and send it as a single parameter, then use `json_decode` and get your full nested object/array